# NextJS GoogleDocs API returns "Must specify at least one request"

Tags: next.js, promise, google-api, cors

Using NextJS, I am trying to create a google document that inserts data from an API into a created google doc.

Currently my process is I generated a new document, grab the ID from the response. I then proceed to use this ID to use the batchUpdate method to try and insertText, however, even though my request works in the Google Workspace playground, I'm getting the following errors:

NETWORK REQUEST:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Must specify at least one request.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

CONSOLE.LOG RESPONSE:

```
Response { 
    type: "cors", 
    url: "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1U3xMrjKO5K4jQp_ppJCBb1qgMehjyQa-eT86Io5ZDeM:batchUpdate", 
    redirected: false, 
    status: 400, 
    ok: false, 
    statusText: "Bad Request", 
    headers: Headers(7), 
    body: ReadableStream, 
    bodyUsed: false 
}
​
body: ReadableStream { locked: false }
​​
locked: false
​​
<prototype>: ReadableStreamPrototype { 
    cancel: cancel(), 
    getReader: getReader(), 
    pipeThrough: pipeThrough(), … 
}
​
bodyUsed: false
​
headers: Headers(7) { "cache-control" → "private", "content-encoding" → "gzip", "content-length" → "125", … }
​​
<entries>
​​
<prototype>: HeadersPrototype { append: append(), delete: delete(), get: get(), … }
​
ok: false
​
redirected: false
​
status: 400
​
statusText: "Bad Request"
​
type: "cors"
​
url: "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1U3xMrjKO5K4jQp_ppJCBb1qgMehjyQa-eT86Io5ZDeM:batchUpdate"
​
<prototype>: ResponsePrototype { clone: clone(), arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer(), blob: blob(), … }
index.tsx:80:16
```

Below is the code that generates the requests. Currently all I am trying to do is just insert text into the document.

The request inside the *fillOutDoc* function works on the Google workshop playground as I mentioned above.

```
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const [documentId, setDocumentId] = useState<string>('');

  useEffect(() => {
    data.forEach((player: any) => {
      console.log(player.name);
    });
  }, [data]);

  const createDoc = (teamName: string) => {
    const fileName: string = `${teamName}`;

    const requestBody: any = {
      requests: [
        {
          insertText: {
            text: 'THIS IS A  BIG OLD TEST TO SEE IF THIS WORKS YA YEET',
            endOfSegmentLocation: {},
          },
        },
      ],
    };
    const parsedRequest: any = JSON.stringify(requestBody);

    fetch(`https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents?title=${fileName}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      //   @ts-ignore
      headers: new Headers({ Authorization: 'Bearer ' + session?.accessToken }),
    })
      .then((res: any) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((val) => {
        console.log(val);
        console.log(val.documentId);
        setDocumentId(val.documentId);
      });
  };

  const fillOutDoc = () => {
    fetch(
      `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${documentId}:batchUpdate`,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
          //   @ts-ignore
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + session?.accessToken,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
        // @ts-ignore
        payload: JSON.stringify({
          requests: [
            {
              insertText: {
                text: 'asdfjasdf',
                endOfSegmentLocation: {},
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      },
    )
      .then((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };
```

I believe I'm following all of Google's code correctly... Maybe I might be better off trying to insert the data into a Google Sheet and then creating a report out of that?

Comment: Where does the error of `Must specify at least one request.` occur in your showing script?

Comment: that doesn't look like something that came from a google quick start guide to me.  What exactly have you been following?

Comment: @Tanaike it occurs in the console of the browser, in the "message" of the network request.

Comment: @DaImTo https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest this has been a point of reference, I can't recall exactly where I got everything from, I've pulled bits and pieces from various tutorials to try and create what I'm after

Comment: Well your not using the official google nodejs client library so its all on you then to figure it out if you want to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

Figured out where I was having the issues, I needed to change the request from "payload" to "body" when in the fillOutDoc function.